# Running the camera using Emgu CV

Tags: c#, visual-studio, emgucv, face-detection

I want to make facial recognition system. Now, I'm trying to run the camera however I'm having a hard time running accessing the camera. Here is my code:

```
public partial class Camera : Form
{
    private Capture capture;
    private HaarCascade haarCascade;
    Timer timer;

    public Camera()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        capture = new Capture();
        haarCascade = new HaarCascade(@"haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml");
        timer = new Timer();
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
        timer.Start();
    }        
}
```

There's an error in `timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1);`.

Here is the error:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.TimeSpan' to 'int'   Attendance_Marking_System   c:\users\redpranger\documents\visual studio 2017\Projects\Attendance_Marking_System\Attendance_Marking_System\Camera.cs 34  Active

Answer (score 2):

The [**Timer.Interval Property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.interval(v=vs.110).aspx) is a property of type `Double`, not a `Timespan`.

Here's the definition of the property:

> Gets or sets the interval, expressed in milliseconds, at which to raise the Elapsed event.

To set the interval at 1 second (1000 milliseconds), set it like this:

```
timer.Interval = 1000;
```

Or in your example, at 1 millisecond:

```
timer.Interval = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 1).TotalMilliseconds;
```

or you can try

```
timer.Interval = 1; // 1ms
```

you don't need to refresh the camera each 1ms i don't think that your camera has that much fps 
so 30ms would be fine in your case 
so try

```
timer.Interval = 30; // for 30 ms
```

Comment: Although your answer is technically correct, I don't see the use of creating a structure just to get the milliseconds.

Comment: you're right in op case actually he don't need to use TimeSpan.
i just wrote it to make him understand that if he want to give the value to interval he need to convert it by using TotalMiliseconds property

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple,
all you have to do is

To set the interval at 1 second (1000 milliseconds), set it like this:

```
timer.Interval = 1000;
```